# Como fazer com que a página carregue apenas após o retorno do getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estou recuperando uma lista em JSON usando a função `jQuery.getJSON`:

```
http=jQuery.getJSON(url);
```

Este código retorna o objeto perfeitamente, porém a requisição demora mais do que o tempo de carregamento da página onde irei inserir os dados. Desta forma, a página carrega com o objeto ainda `null`.

Como fazer para que a página carregue somente após o retorno do `getJSON`?

Comment: coloca a requisição completa para ficar mais facil o entendimento

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passe um callback para o `getJSON`:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(dados) {
    // aqui o json já carregou e pode ser acessado como "dados"
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Então, a meu ver, é o servidor quem deve realizar a busca e embutir os dados diretamente na página que **será** servida (como resultado do processamento no servidor).

Na maior parte dos casos (e digo isso apenas porque, em alguns casos, como quando não temos acesso ao servidor, é realmente justificável realizar esta tarefa via Javascript), não existe propósito em servir uma página em branco, e que continua "congelada" até que uma requisição AJAX retorne os dados do servidor. Eu recomendo que você não utilize AJAX, e ao invés disso, gere a página já com os dados embutidos em lado servidor.

Porém, caso você necessite aplicar este modelo, basta utilizar o terceiro parâmetro (`callback`) da função `getJSON()` (que é a função a ser executada após o recebimento da resposta) para prosseguir com a execução de maneira assíncrona:

```
$.getJSON(v_url, v_data, function(data){
    prosseguirExecucao(data);
}
```

Onde `data` será o objeto literal com seus dados.

Caso queira uma execução síncrona (que, como o @bfavaretto apontou, é aquela categoria de chamada de rotina que **impede o programa de processar qualquer outra coisa até que a rotina chamada termine**), basta executar, antes do script anterior, o seguinte trecho:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
```

**EDIT**: o trecho acima modifica a forma como **todas** as requisições AJAX, dali por diante, serão feitas pelo jQuery. Uma vez que `getJSON()` nada mais é do que uma abreviação de sintaxe para uma chamada `AJAX()` comum, ela sofrerá o efeito do `ajaxSetup()` também, mas se a sua intenção é fazer apenas a requisição do JSON de forma síncrona, você precisa restaurar a configuração para o modo assíncrono novamente após o `getJSON()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: true
});
```

Comment: Só lembrando que a execução síncrona deixará a página travada até o recebimento do JSON.

Comment: passando o callback funcionou certinho! Muito agradecido. Valeu pessoal!

Comment: @Dayan, não prefere marcar esta resposta como a certa em vez da minha? Ela explica melhor e é mais completa...

Comment: @bfavaretto, sua resposta está corretíssima e bem objetiva, acredito que resolva a maior parte dos casos , e mais a mais, você manja beeeem mais de jQuery que eu, então nada mais justo que sua resposta ter sido aceita! :D
Deixo aqui minha resposta como complemento para quem precisar de um pouco mais de background, e ressalato que editei a mesma para incluir sua observação e mais uma outra que achei útil :)

Comment: Obrigado Rui! Independente de quanto eu sei de jQuery, produzi uma resposta rápida, enquanto a sua é bem mais completa. Ainda acho a sua melhor :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método `$.holdReady()`, desta forma:

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    // algum processamento com o json

    $.holdReady(false);
});
```

Assim, você pode utilizar o método `.ready()` do jQuery para executar seus scripts somente após o retorno do json.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // código executado depois do carregamento do json
});
```

Veja mais informações neste [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/).